# Table columns with widths set by m{} appear to be incorrect

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment

I am using R and Sweave to produce tables for a report, and one of the generated tables is not playing nicely with the `m{}` definition of column width.  The `.tex` file produced by R/Sweave has the following code (I've changed the lines to gibberish to protect the content of the report).

```
% PREAMBLE
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}                           % Set the document class, paper size, font
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=0.75in,right=0.75in]{geometry}  % Using geometry to set the margins
\usepackage{lscape}                                                 % Using lscape to help rotate pages as needed
\usepackage{color}                                                  % Lets us define colors
\usepackage{colortbl}                                               % Lets us colorize our tables
\usepackage{threeparttable}                                         % Supposedly allows us to have notes on tables
\usepackage{array}                                                  % Allows for more precision in table layouts
\usepackage{hhline}                                                 % Grants access to hhline
\usepackage{xcolor}                                                 % Alternate rows of color

% COLORS
\definecolor{mydarkgrey}{RGB}{96,96,96}
\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{224,224,224}

% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}             % Remove indentation
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1.1pt}      % Makes the lines look nicer in tables
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}           % For Sweave

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Table Caption}
\vspace{12pt}
\begin{threeparttable}
\rowcolors{2}{mygrey}{}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.7in}| %
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54in}| %
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54in}| %
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54in}| %
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54in}| %
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54in}| %
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54in}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{mydarkgrey}
  \color{white}A & \color{white}B & \color{white}\% & \color{white}C & \color{white}\% & \color{white}D & \color{white}\% \\
  Non-significant issue in the issues & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Significant issue in the things & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Loss of losses & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Returning to the consent document & 1 & 25.0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Substantive logical fallacies & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Duplicated replication of disease & 3 & 75.0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 50 \\
  Fantastical subgenus & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Deviant characteristics consistent w/James' syndrome & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Scores $\ge$ 10 with Cohen's adjustment\tnote{2} & 1 & 25 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 50 \\
  Centralized optimization context > 5\tnote{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Subdermal O$^{2}$ desat rate <85\% for >10\% of the record\tnote{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  Other & 3 & 75 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 50 \\
  Total & 4 & 100 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 50 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
\scriptsize \item[] \textit{Percentages are given by column, excepting the final total.}
\item[] \textit{Percentages will not total to 100.}
\item[1] \textit{Note 1.}
\item[2] \textit{Note 2.}
\item[3] \textit{Note 3.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\normalsize

\end{document}
```

By my math, 3.7in + 6*(0.54in) should be 6.94 inches, which should fit nicely inside the 7 inch page area that I have (`\the\linewidth` says that the width is 505.89 pts, which is 7 inches).  However, my output is this:

[image]

The width of the last 6 columns doesn't appear to be 0.54in, and I'm not sure why. I tried designating the widths in pts as well, and the same problem persists, as it does when I changed the column type to `p{}` instead of `m{}`.

Comment: Try `\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{3.7in}|*{6}{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.54in}@{}|}}`

Comment: And [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: You have 2*\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth between each column and \tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth at either side

Comment: By far this is my best experience yet on StackExchange. You guys provided me exactly what I needed to adjust things. Perfect. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following for your `tabular` column specification:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr 3.7in-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}| %
                *{6}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr 0.54in-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}}
```

which removes the `\tabcolsep` on either side of a column (so `2\tabcolsep` for each column), plus the `\arrayrulewidth` where necessary (left & right for the first column, while the second to seventh columns removes the right rule as well).

The output of Sweave is automated, leading to the duplication within the column specification. However, the condensed use of the column specification `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` is from/provided by the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array).